# Linking mysql tables

Tags: mysql, join

i'm fairly new to mysql/php and i', trying to grab data from 2 tables:

1. organization_dep (id, orgid, depname )
2. organization (id, orgname )

what I am trying to do is link the tables and echo the results so it comes as table with two columns: `organization Name` and `organization Department Name`

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I don't think you're stuck in all and every single step involved, from SQL query to required HTML. You should edit your question and try to be more specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "JOIN" tag on your question is actually the right key word.

```
SELECT
    org.orgname,
    dep.depname
FROM
    organization_dep dep
    INNER JOIN organization org
        ON dep.orgid = org.id
```

Read more about joining tables in the [MySQL Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html).